# Are line references capitalised?

Tags: orthography, writing-style, capitalization

When I write, I treat references as though they are proper nouns; for example, *Chapter 10*, *Section 10*, *Line 10*, *Page 10*. (As opposed to *chapter 10*, *section 10*, *line 10*, *page 10* - no capital letter.)

[My short forms would be *Ch.10*, *s.10*, *l.10*, *p.10*]

Until now, I've never been picked up on it. I wrote a piece that involved numerous references to numbered lines. Here is an example from my piece:

> Ham makes further attempts to connect with the reader in **Line 26**, where she writes...

This was corrected to "**l**ine 26" (no capital).

I can't really explain why I think references should be capitalised, but I surely must have picked it up from somewhere.

So, my question is - if not common practice, is there anything *wrong* with capitalising (line) references? Are there any style guides that have a preference for capitalised references?

Comment: I'd not be inclined to capitalize unless the lines are captioned "Line 26", et al.  If they are simply numbered, eg, in the right margin then the reference is not a "proper name".

Comment: @HotLicks I was actually thinking about that just then. Indeed, they were numbered in the margin without the word "Line".